# Bevel not working on joined edges

Tags: modeling, edges, bevel

I'm trying to bevel the edges of the head on this screw.

It seems to work for the most part, but the edges that have been joined together from separate shapes don't seem to work.

[image: 3D model of screw, bevel twists and breaks it.]

I've tried removing any extra faces inside, hiting the "remove doubles" button and joining the two shapes by the corners / edges so it's one solid shape.

[image: Warped screw head, showing the two shapes are properly joined.]

Any ideas how I can fix this so I get a smooth, even bevel on the corners around the screw head like this?

[image: Bevel behaving correctly on different corner]

Comment: you have inconsistent normals, recalculate them (ctrl-n)

Comment: add bevel modifier

Comment: Jaroslav, please make that an answer so I can give you proper credit - that fixed it!